# Configure dnsmasq as IPv6 nameserver but let router do routing (and maybe IP address assignment)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, router, ipv6, dnsmasq

*Suggestions welcome!*

I'm moving DHCP and DNS services from a combined router (192.168.0.1) to a separate system (running on 192.168.0.2) with dnsmasq. **I want the first system to be the default route and the second system to handle dns. How should I configure dnsmasq for this?**

So far it works fine for IPv4 all system gets addresses and the correct name server. But when inspecting IPv6 settings in the terminal I see it is not using my internal DNS, but is using the IPv6 addresses of the ISP's DNS servers.

How should I configure so the IPv6 addresses are routed via the router and the name-server lookup is directed to my local name-server. The configuration options for v6 and examples I have found so far seem to only be suitable if both router and name-server are running the same machine.

Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated

Config:

```
$ grep -v '^#' <dnsmasq.conf |uniq
server=127.0.0.1#5053
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.1
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0
```

version:

```
$ dnsmasq -v
Dnsmasq version 2.75  Copyright (c) 2000-2015 Simon Kelley
```

edit:
*resolv.conf* (but this is not where I see the IPv6 name-server - they can be seen in on an Android device on the network)

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 192.168.0.2
```

Open ports

```
$ sudo netstat -l -u -p -n
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           542/dnsmasq     
udp        0      0 192.168.0.2:53          0.0.0.0:*                           542/dnsmasq     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           542/dnsmasq     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5053          0.0.0.0:*                           603/cloudflared 
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                542/dnsmasq
```

Comment: Questions: (1) Which Linux distribution? (2) Does [this issue](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/4291) apply here? (3) Please add to the post the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`. (4) Aren't you missing "server=IPv6-address" in  `dnsmasq.conf`?

Comment: 1. The distribution is some xenisal (16.04.5 ?) for arm based distribution.  2 maybe - not sure what I am looking for 4 Yes but I only want to change the name server in the IPv6 case

Comment: How could I write this system as server=ipv6addr ? It is not static as in IPv4 ? (Links or suggestions what keywords to google with would be appreciated)